# Fast numerical oscillatory integral with fixed support points.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, oscillatory-integral

I have to numerically evaluate

$$\int_0^\beta d\tau e^{i \nu_n \tau} G(\tau)$$

for a large number on $\nu_n$. $G(\tau)$ is expensive to evaluate. Currently I'm using Quadpacks dqawo (double qaudpack adaptive weighted oscillatory), which integrals of the type

$$\int_a^b dx \sin(\omega x) f(x)$$

and

$$\int_a^b dx \cos(\omega x) f(x).$$

I use these routines to integrate the real and imaginary part seperatly, but since these routines are adaptive they will calculate two different sets of $G(\tau)$ for each $\nu_n$. So I am considering evaluating a fixed grid of $G(\tau_i)$ once, which I then evaluate by something like Simpsons rule for all $\nu_n$.

Is there something like Simpsons rule, which is adapted especially for oscillatory integrals and which uses an equidistant grid, such that I can evaluate only one set of $G(\tau_i)$

Comment: I guess that is a *Fourier-Matsubara Green Function* in the 'discrete domain'. Try to write down the analitycal continuation above or below the real axis which 'moves' the whole problem to a 'continuous frequency' domain $\left\{\omega\right\}$. I guess it will become easier to analyse.

Comment: You are right, this is a Matsubara Green Function, but I can't use the analytic continuation, because I only have it numerically.